# Pesquisar na Tabela dinâmica com uma macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Estou tentando configurar um botão para copiar o valor de uma célula, colar em um dos filhos da tabela dinâmica e dar ok.

```vb
Sub Botão17_Clique()
'
' Botão17_Clique Macro
'

'
    Range("H3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotFields("Dispositivo Operado"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotFields( _
        "Dispositivo Operado")
        .PivotItems("691441").Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

O botão funciona porém quando eu mudo o valor da Célula `H3` o mesmo não funciona mais. Preciso que quando eu mudar o valor de `("H3")` esse valor venha para `PivotItems("H3").Visible = True`.
<sup>Não sei se consegui explicar corretamente.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar uma atualização da tabela dinâmica no final do código:

```vb
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotCache.Refresh
```